# Correct way of getting webelements in <ul> selenium

Tags: java, selenium

What is the correct way of finding elements in list like this:

```
<div class="aui-header-primary">
    <ul class="aui-nav __skate" style="width: auto;">
      <li>
      <li>
      <li>
      <li>
      <li id="create-menu">
  </ul>
</div>
```

This works, but it doesn't look like a good solution:

```
WebElement div = driver.findElement(By.className("aui-header-primary"));
WebElement ul = div.findElement(By.tagName("ul"));
List<WebElement> list = ul.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
```

What is the correct way to do that?

Comment: `findElements` (how you are doing it right now) is the correct way to do this. What do you think is wrong with your solution? Seems fine to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with your code, but if you want to do it in one line:

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".aui-header-primary ul li"));
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I meant